# closing specific file from Matlab editor

Tags: matlab

Is there's any command line interface to close a single file from all the open files?
I know I can close all files yet I sometimes work from a network location and I would like to close a set of files with a single script.

Comment: file? as in `fclose(fid)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For recent MATLABs you can close files that are open in the MATLAB editor with something like the following:

```
matlab.desktop.editor.findOpenDocument( 'C:\my_function.m' ).close()
```

For older MATLABs you can try something like this (but I don't have an old installation to test):

```
com.mathworks.mlservices.MLEditorServices.closeDocument( 'C:\my_function.m' )
```